# import namespace in Azure function when creating csx in portal

Tags: azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I need to create an Azure Function in the portal using the Function editor to create the .csx using version 2.
I am new to the .net world coming from Python universe and the namespace import gives me a hard time.
Goal is to create a client to encrypt data using KeyVault key, something like: `CryptographyClient x = new CryptographyClient();`.

To do so I first need to enable that Class...but How I do so?
Do I have to use that #r statement for including assemblies or just put
`using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys.Cryptography;`
or do i have to use some nuget import in a function.proj file?

Whatever I tried it is not working and as a beginner I have to tell the documentation is not very helpful.

Comment: still no, that is what I had tried already. the package is imported but I am not smart enough to use it apparently.

Comment: I thereafter stated "using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys;" to make it available but still get an error saying "The type or namespace name 'Azure' could not be found"

Answer (score 0):

To use NuGet packages in a `2.x` C# function, upload a [`function.proj`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-csharp#using-nuget-packages) file to the function's folder in the function app's file system. Here is an example `function.proj` file that adds a reference to `Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys` version `4.0.0`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Keys" Version="4.0.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

After file created, assemblies will be added to function host environment. You do not need manually to add #r statement.